# JWTAuth::fromUser($newRegistredUser) give me token for current userthat are logged in

Tags: laravel, jwt

I am creating a new user like this :

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'ion';
$user->save;
$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user)
```

And here I receive token from loggedIn user (for example James).
But I want to generate a token for the freshly created user.
Every user that I gave there I receive token for logged in user.
I tried `$user = User::find(1)`<--here is another user but I receive wrong token for user that is logged in.
I think that problem is that I have middleware JWT because when I try in another controller where don't have this middleware I receive right token.